# How to find the the most value index of N index from matrix M MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, indexing, find

Suppose I have a matrix M 500x500

and I want to find first 100 index that have the most value in M

my idea was sort the data M in descending order and use find to compare

```
[x,y] = find(M == sort(M(:),'descend'), 100, 'first');
```

But when I run the program I found error

I think it probably `M == sort(M(:),'descend')` this part

Can you help me please?

Comment: try using `M(:,:)` instead of `M(:)` as your matrix is two dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `find`. Just use the second output of `sort`:

```
[~, iSorted] = sort(M(:),'descend');
[x y] = ind2sub(size(M), iSorted(1:100));
```